# Exception in ws-outbound gateway : org.springframework.ws.InvalidXmlException: Could not parse XML if beta ( ß ) character comes in soap response

Tags: spring, soap, spring-integration, websphere-8

I am facing exception :  `org.springframework.ws.InvalidXmlException`:  in spring-integration ws outbound gateway if any special character like beta (ß) gama comes in the web service response.

My code works on local (windows box) but this exception comes when my application is deployed on IBM Websphere (unix box).

Please advise.

Thanks 
Ram

Comment: Well, looks like there is nothing on the Spring Integration (or Spring at all)  side. Since you confirm that it works on another environment, unless Websphere, I'd suggest you to ask the question on WAS support, like: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/public

Comment: Can you post the full response body and headers somewhere?

Comment: Artem, How are we sure that this will not fail as we do not have any charset attribute in ws outbound gateway. Can we explicitly define charset while parsing the soap response. Please HELP !!

Comment: I am unable to get the soap response as this is failing in ws outbound gateway.

Comment: This is the soap response which i get from soap ui :  <LOCATION>
              <Address>RAMß</Address></LOCATION>

Comment: I have got this error : org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapEnvelopeException: Could not access envelope: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffffffff) was found in the element content of the document. Message being parsed: ; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffffffff) was found in the element content of the document. Message being parsed:

Comment: I tried to change the SOAP Factory and MessageFactory to point to sun jax ws implementation rather than IBM WS of  thinclient.jar but again it is picking of IBM only com.ibm.ws.webservices.soap  javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl
javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl

Comment: Well, how about to try the same with the `AxiomSoapMessageFactory`? Seems for me WAS knows nothing about that and you can just bypass its hell. At least I always used `axiom` and my apps worked on JBOSS, WAS and WebLogic as well.

Comment: Which version of axiom-api.jar are you using  to make it certified with spring-ws / ws-outbound gateway ?

Comment: Ovreridden afterPropertiesSet() of SaajSoapMessageFactory and used   messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(); instead of      messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(messageFactoryProtocol) ; Hence now it is able to look up from SoapMessageFactory Impl from System Property.

Comment: After specifying these properties in custom property of WAS :
1.)javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl   
2.)javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPFactory1_1Impl and modifying the SaajSoapMessageFactory afterProperties() to change to messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance() way so that it can look up from system property. It is working fine. :-)